# javascript regex to match all custom commented out sections, but not other text

Tags: javascript, regex

Say I have a html doc like so:

```
<!--FOO-->
  some text
<!--BAR-->

some other text

<!--FOO-->
some more text
<!--BAR-->
```

How can I write a javascript regex that matches both cases of

```
<!--FOO-->anytext<!--BAR-->
```

but not the text in between ('some other text' in this case).

My regex that I thought would work is

```
/<!--FOO-->(.|\n)*<!--BAR-->/
```

but it catches the 'some other text' as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the non-greedy operator `?`, like this:

```
/<!--FOO-->(.|\n)*?<!--BAR-->/
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/kP4xB4/2)

A slightly better version would be this, letting you actually capture the text between the comments:

```
/<!--FOO-->((?:\n|.)*?)<!--BAR-->/
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/rW5mN8/1)

That said, parsing HTML with regex rarely ends well... [See here for the classic explanation of the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). You are better off using a library, unless your parsing is limited to the very simple case in your question.

Comment: thanks.  It is a very simple case on this occasion, and if it gets more complex i'll look into a library.